# Insert records from two different tables into one

Tags: ms-access-2016

Table 1: **MSISDN Table**

```
-----------------------------
ID       MSISDN        Number
-----------------------------
```

Table 2: **Account Manager Table**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
ID    Account Manager Name    Account Manager Email   Count
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 3: **Assignment Table**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID    Account Manager ID    Account Manager Name    Account Manager Email   Count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Whenever there is a new entry in MSISDN table, I want to insert MSISDN_Number along with ID, Account Manager Name, Account Manager Email from Account Manager Table INTO Assignment Table automatically.
There is one condition on Account Manager Table that I want to select only records for lowest count under count column in Account Manager Table.

My Approach:
1. To get details from Account Manager Table for lowest count:

```
SELECT TOP 1 AccountManager_Table.[ID], AccountManager_Table.[Account Manager Name], AccountManager_Table.[Account Manager Email]
    FROM AccountManager_Table
    Where AccountManager_Table.[Count] =(SELECT MIN(Count) from AccountManager_Table);
```

2.Not working INSERT Into Query:

```
INSERT INTO Assignment_Table ( [Account Manager ID], [Account Manager Name], [Account Manager Email],[MSISDN No] )
Values(
  (SELECT TOP 1 AccountManager_Table.[ID], AccountManager_Table.[Account Manager Name], AccountManager_Table.[Account Manager Email]
  FROM AccountManager_Table
  WHERE (((AccountManager_Table.Count)=(SELECT MIN(Count) from AccountManager_Table)))
  ),
  (SELECT MSISDN_Table.[MSISDN Number]
  FROM MSISDN_Table
  WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM AccountManager_Table)
  )
);
```

I want to insert MSISDN and Account Manager Details in assignment table together.Please help :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make both of your SELECT statements into a single SELECT statement.

Look at how to do a JOIN:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Also, your third table doesn't have a column for MSISDN Number, so you'll have to add that column.  The columns being fed into the table need to match to columns that exist in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes there is a column for msisdn in assignment table which i missed above.I assume i cant use joins becoz there is nothing common in Account Manager and MSISDN Table. What i want is : Whenever new MSISDN is inserted in MSISDN table it should be assigned to manager from account manager table who has lowest count and all manager details along with MSISDN should be in Assignment table.

Comment: There's a couple of ways to do this.  i would do a 2-step where you INSERT the Account Manager ID and then have another process that performs an UPDATE to the MSISDN field.  Also, I advise against putting "Account Manager Name" and "Account Manager Email" into that third table since this is purely data redundancy which can go out of sync.